# Create ext3 partition on external drive from Windows 7

Tags: command-line, partitioning, formatting, ext

Are there free CLI tools for Windows (7) which allow me to partition and format an ext3 file system on a external USB drive from Windows natively? I am *not* looking for a solution with a bootable live medium or a virtual machine.

Thanks for sharing your experiences.

Comment: You could try CYGWIN: http://superuser.com/questions/424907/how-do-i-format-a-drive-as-ext4-on-windows-7. Additionally: http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86%2Fe2fsprogs%2Fe2fsprogs-1.42.12-1&grep=hat

Answer (score 1):

Easus partition manager, and other partitioning programs for windows will format in ext.  I have used easus particularly in XP to do it. (the home version because it was free)
Note: some of the partitioning programs can have a setting for showing "removables" or not, in the situation that mabey you do not see the disk at first.

"ext2fsd" If you then want to see what is going on via the system at that point, you will need a driver for that file system.  http://www.ext2fsd.com/

**ADDING:**
Need CLI, the next Program that it brought to mind is Paragons partitioning tools. http://kb.paragon-software.com/paragon/include/templ/object2.jsp?catId=2124&objId=1343&statId=1954834&foLang=en  <-- as we can see at this link paragon provides for scripting, in many of thier products, and also for scripting thier high end partitioning programs .  I have no idea how that would work, or if it would even do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately you did not read and answer my question. EaseUS (with 'e') Partition Manager Home, which is the only free version, does not offer a command line interface. Thanks also for the ext2fsd info, but that's also not what the question is about.

Comment: Ohh, I never would have figured that you would have "prefered" a CMD interface.  So it is ok if this partitioning tool might be large and have a bunch of unnessisary stuff, as long as it would work via a CMDprompt ?

Comment: Yes, that would be ok. The CLI part is necessary for automation purposes. The paragon partitioning tool does offer scripting, but, like EaseUS, not for the free version.

Comment: Your question doesn't ever define what your trying to do. If it was me though, if I was looking for a scripting exe, I would want it to be tiny, fast, portable, free, simple and perfect. if it was For scripting only, I would probably not even want a GUI as that would add to the size. A gparted with windows wings.  I do not remember if having the windows ex2 driver item installed would allow for the sytems own formatting tools to work.

Comment: What are you trying to tell me? I asked a simple, clear question. What I'm trying to do in detail is not relevant. Yes, like you, I would prefer such a perfect command line tool - like Linux' fdisk and mkfs. But since this is not Christmas I limited the criteria to CLI and free, if there is a perfect tool without overhead, I'm even more happy.

Answer (score -1):

You can use to live-cd of Gparted and with unetbootin you can write it on a Usb key (Formated in format Fat32)

[Gparted Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/0.22.0-2/gparted-live-0.22.0-2-i586.iso/download?use_mirror=garr)

Comment: The question asks a Windows CLI method (explained in comments, needed for scripting), for ext3 rather than fat32, and excludes use of a bootable live medium or virtual machine.  So your answer doesn't do a good job of responding to the question.