# How do I format a drive as EXT4 on Windows 7?

Tags: ext4

I'm trying to create an ext4 file system on an external drive. The partition manager I usually use, EASEUS Partition Master, doesn't support ext4. What are some free alternatives?

Edit: It turns out MiniTools Partition Wizard supports ext4.

Comment: Boot a livecd, in a VM, and yadda, yadda, yadda, and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hmm, I haven't tried this, but Cygwin has mke2fs in the e2fsprogs package.  Take a look at:

[How to format Ext2 in Windows XP?](https://superuser.com/questions/314997/how-to-format-ext2-in-windows-xp) and the caveat about special device names the Answer mentions: http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html

Cygwin is over at: http://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: wow, does this REALLY have to be more complicated than a simple utility allowing you to choose your drive and format it with a few clicks of effort? damn I'm lazy...

Comment: @David: Welcome to the world of power-user tasks on Windows :)

Comment: @David: Welcome to the world of using Unix things on Windows, or Windows things on Unix, or any other cross-ecosystem things :)

Comment: @David have a look at https://chocolatey.org/, then it's just `cinst cygwin` away before you can utilize all it's filesystem types

Answer (score 27):

MiniTool partition wizard is a free (for home use) partition manager that can format a partition as EXT2/3/4 from windows - http://www.partitionwizard.com

Answer (score 1):

I believe HP USB Disk storage format tools might help you out (http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=197).  Also checkout Hiren (http://www.hiren.info/), I know they have a couple of formatting tools.

Comment: The HP thing does *not* format ext4, it only formats NTFS and FAT.